# How to decode audio/video bitstream with little information

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, codec

I'm completely new to video/audio formats, containers, and protocols. However, I have to figure out how to decode a bitstream that contains audio and video. I do not know the transport protocol, container format, or codecs used -- but I have been able to deduce a few things:

- It's not RTP
- It's over UDP on port 443
- Audio and video are in datagrams
- audio datagram payloads are always 76 bytes in length, and there are about 42 of them a second.
- video datagram payloads are a maximum of 536 bytes, average is around 500 bytes, and there are about 62 of them a second.

How should I even begin to try to decode it?

Comment: Have you tried saving a large chunk and playing it back with VLC or decoding with FFMPEG?